# Rationale why is macro redefinition without undef leads to ill-formed program

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, language-design

According the [standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.replace) macro redefinition is prohibited without using `#undef` before:

> But the following redefinitions are invalid:
>
> ```
> #define OBJ_LIKE    (0)         // different token sequence
> #define OBJ_LIKE    (1 - 1)     // different whitespace
> ```

At the same time it's allowed to `#undef` for macros that were not defined at all before:

> It is ignored if the specified identifier is not currently defined as a macro name.

I'm interested what is the rationale for this, i.e. forbidding redefinition without `#undef` in the middle? Some compiler optimization purposes or what?

Comment: IDK but I imagine that the rationale is that #undef without previous definition is harmless, but redefinition of existing macro most likely isn't.

Comment: Because silently ignoring it is hightly unintuitive? I've removed the `language-lawyer` tag because you're looking for an explanation, not a quote from the standard.

Comment: It is for to fail fast when you have made programming errors. Compile time errors are cheapest to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it was inherited from C.

ISO/IEC 9899:1990 §6.8.3 (AKA C90) contains similar wording:

> An identifier currently defined as a macro without use of lparen (an *object-like* macro) may be redefined by another `#define` preprocessing directive provided that the second definition is an object-like macro definition and the two replacement lists are identical.
>
> An identifier currently defined as a macro using lparen (a *function-like* macro) may be redefined by another `#define` preprocessing directive provided that the second definition is a function-like macro definition that has the same number and spelling of parameters, and the two replacement lists are identical.

And looking at N802 produced by WG14 (https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n802.pdf) "Rationale for International Standard - Programming Language - C" §6.8.3, the reason is stated as:

> The Committee desired to disallow "pernicious redefinitions'' such as
> (in header1.h)
>
> ```
> #define NBUFS 10
> ```
>
> (in header.h)
>
> ```
> #define NBUFS 12
> ```
>
> which are clearly invitations to serious bugs in a program. There remained, however, the question of "benign redefinitions,'' such as
> (in header1.h)
>
> ```
> #define NULL_DEV 0
> ```
>
> (in header.h)
>
> ```
> #define NULL_DEV 0
> ```
>
> The Committee concluded that safe programming practice is better served by allowing benign redefinition where the definitions are the same. This allows independent headers to specify their understanding of the proper value for a symbol of interest to each, with diagnostics generated only if the definitions differ.

So "benign" redefinitions are encouraged, where the alternative would be something like:

```cpp
#ifdef SPEED_OF_LIGHT
#if SPEED_OF_LIGHT != 299792458
#error Some other header defines SOME_UNIVERSAL_CONSTANT wrong
#endif
#else
#define SPEED_OF_LIGHT 299792458
#endif
```

Simply `#define SPEED_OF_LIGHT 299792458` will generate a warning if another header defines it differently.

---

And a similar thing for `#undef`. The rationale given for §6.8.3.5:

> It is explicitly permitted to `#undef` a macro that has no current definition. This capability is exploited in conjunction with the standard library (see §7.1.8).

Where §7.1.8 of C99 / §7.1.7 of C90 says:

> The use of `#undef` to remove any macro definition will also ensure than an actual function is referred to.

For example, a standard library header might have `double abs(double);` as well as `#define abs(x) _BUILTIN_abs(x)`, and `#undef abs` was legal and allowed you to make sure `abs` referred to a bona fide function.

Of course, this doesn't apply to C++, where standard library functions cannot be macros. But the other rationale ("It is explicitly permitted to `#undef` a macro that has no current definition") still applies, i.e., "the committee says so".

Answer (score 3):

It's disallowed because silently redefining a macro to mean something else is a likely mistake.
Consider the following example:

```cpp
// in assertions.hpp
#define assert(expr, msg) if (!expr) std::cout << msg << '\n';
```

```cpp
#include "assertions.hpp"
// ...
#include <cassert> // could be included directly or indirectly
// ...

int main() {
    // expected to fail and print "huh ?!" to std::cout
    assert(false, "huh ?!");
    // may expand to:
    // ((false, "huh ?!") ? void() : __fail("huh ?!"))
}
```

This assertion now succeeds because `assert` in `<cassert>` redefined what an assertion is.
In general, re-defining things may have a number of consequences:

- simply producing compiler errors
- silently redefining global constants to have different values
- silently redefining function-like macros to have different behavior

Keep in mind that the order of `#include`s matters and that every macro can spill into any other header this way.
Bugs related to macro re-definitions may be very difficult to track down.

If you want to repurpose a macro name, you can just `#undef` it first.

Comment: I got your point, but unfortunately your example with `assert` forbid C++ [standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/macro.names#1): `A translation unit that includes a standard library header shall not #define or #undef names declared in any standard library header.`

Comment: @αλεχολυτ   It wouldn't be difficult to construct a similar example, in which two headers define the same (non-standard) macro to have different expansions, then some source file includes both headers, uses the macro, and has unexpected and undiagnosed behaviours.    Such situations occur regularly in the real world when code is modified, and a new header included in existing source file for some reason unrelated to the affected macro.   Better to simply have the redefinition diagnosed.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot check MACRO definition, we only can check if MACRO is defined or not.

So, if you want to check that `#undef` is only done on defined MACRO, you might check it yourself:

```
#ifdef MY_MACRO
# undef MY_MACRO
#else
# error "Expected previous definition"
#end
```

For redefining MACRO, it is not possible

```
#define MY_MACRO some_def

// #ifdef MY_MACRO // only check it is defined not its definition
                   // so cannot differentiate for below two cases

#define MY_MACRO some_def    // OK (same def)
#define MY_MACRO another_def // Invalid
```